# Value check in nested javascript object (might not exist)

Tags: javascript

Is there an elegant and concise way to avoid doing something like this to check a value deep within an object member hierarchy in javascript?

```
handlerInput.supportsDisplay = function() {
   return  this.requestEnvelope.context && 
           this.requestEnvelope.context.System && 
           this.requestEnvelope.context.System.device && 
           this.requestEnvelope.context.System.device.supportedInterfaces && 
           this.requestEnvelope.context.System.device.supportedInterfaces.Display;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no concise way to do it in plain JavaScript, unless you use a helper function or a third-party library.

There is a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) (at Stage 1 as of August 2018) to add the `?.` operator to JavaScript which does exactly what you want.

With that proposal accepted, you would be able to use `?.` instead of `.` anywhere where a property might be missing, so your code would become:

```
// careful: this syntax is not available yet
var hasDisplay = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context?.System?.device?.supportedInterfaces?.Display
```

Comment: As a steward of StackOverflow, you should be voting to close as duplicate rather than providing a new answer to something that has been asked and answered thoroughly already.

Answer (score 0):

This is cheating, but you can use the `_.get` function from Lodash

```
_.get(validations, "path.to.nested.prop");
```

From the docs

> Gets the value at path of object. If the resolved value is undefined, the defaultValue is returned in its place.

Comment: I guess he was asking if he could just check the nested value without using dots(a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h) and you did that only just with lodash.

Comment: I disagree. He wants to do it in one line. That's what you `_.get`

Comment: I disagree that it's cheating.  The LoDash library makes many, many things clearer and safer.  I don't go anywhere without LoDash :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an NPM module that allows you to query by a string path.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-path-resolver
http://www.twelvetone.tv/docs/developer-tools/npm-modules/js-path-resolver

Here's a codepen
https://codepen.io/Flamenco/pen/xaVKjR/?editors=1111

For your use case:

```
import resolver from 'js-path-resolver'
const info = resolver(handlerInput, 'requestEnvelope.context.System.device.supportedInterface.Display', {onError:'continue'})
const hasDisplay = info.exists
const display = info.get()
```

In a nutshell, you split the string, then try to resolve the path, one string at a time.  There are all sorts of issues implementing this, such as escaping dots, handling array indexes, etc, so using a library makes life much easier.  In this library, you can also set, and delete the resolved path.